# how to insert a 128d vector into mongodb database using pymongo in python

Tags: python, mongodb, vector, pymongo

I'm trying to insert an 128d vector which I generated for a face in a image containing multiple faces into MongoDB collection(vectors). I'm using the famous dlib library for generating the 128d vector. When I try to insert this vector into mongodb collection I got "cannot encode object error". The error is as below.

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 610, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: dlib.vector([-0.078586, 0.0277601, 0.02961, 0.0263595, -0.0423636, -0.0593996, -0.0353243, -0.157486, 0.169706, -0.0115421, 0.215085, 0.0998522, -0.230498, -0.0380571, -0.0662888, 0.0504411, -0.0678306, -0.0943572, -0.123836, -0.0879753, -0.0753862, 0.000870723, 0.0786572, 0.0651935, -0.0732055, -0.294396, -0.108001, -0.122248, 0.0798309, -0.0558914, -0.00326786, -0.00399151, -0.201238, -0.0997921, 0.0628334, -0.0214193, -0.0168998, -0.00545083, 0.260324, -0.0224971, -0.137103, 0.0410911, 0.0381873, 0.228159, 0.101016, 0.0886697, 0.0711474, -0.12792, 0.0942142, -0.139165, 0.0716797, 0.147697, 0.0957785, -0.00807651, 0.0464634, -0.18575, 0.00923027, 0.0976636, -0.24552, 0.145688, 0.0765331, -0.0418556, -0.0641425, 0.00440269, 0.181549, 0.134916, -0.0709987, -0.182558, 0.168222, -0.238072, 0.041242, 0.10536, -0.0684752, -0.199106, -0.233173, 0.00511742, 0.417584, 0.176161, -0.11886, 0.0600367, -0.16006, -0.0130243, 0.0705707, -0.0569518, -0.136003, 0.0180192, -0.0785295, -0.00361975, 0.212427, 0.0941055, -0.064303, 0.178207, 0.00868456, 0.0107785, 0.0646739, 0.0319019, -0.11788, -0.046726, -0.129802, 0.00561518, -0.0292626, -0.0468726, 0.132234, 0.00913511, -0.159603, 0.0933984, -0.0159525, -0.0224207, 0.00211018, 0.119351, -0.154814, -0.0764414, 0.170755, -0.303818, 0.304808, 0.111342, 0.066825, 0.12282, 0.0600208, 0.0596608, -0.0402757, -0.017425, -0.0706421, -0.102285, 0.0109511, -0.0790169, 0.18963, 0.0300883])
```

I did try to convert this 128d vector to list, np array but no help.

Is there a way to insert 128d vector as it is using pymongo in MongoDB since I want compare 128d vectors for similarity later on.

The part of the code where I'm trying to insert vector into mongodb is as below.

```
face_descriptor = facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
        print(face_descriptor)
        result = db.vectors.insert_one({"image": face_descriptor, "paths" : f})
```

your help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How are you planning (or since this is an old post, how did you) to query mongo for similar faces?

Comment: @StevenCarlson For every input face I extracted 128d face embedding and inserted into mongo collection. For a new face(for which you want to find similar faces) calculate the 128d embedding and find the euclidian distance between new face embedding and face embedding stored in mongo collection. If the euclidian distance is less than 0.6(dlib machine learning library is trained like this) then the faces are similar else not.

Answer (score 1):

I just converted it to a list to save in DB.

```
face_descriptor_list = list(facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape))
db.vectors.insert_one({"image": face_descriptor_list, "paths" : f})
```

Retrieval:

After fetching it from DB, convert back to dlib vector

```
img_data = db.vectors.find_one({...})
face_descriptor = dlib.vector(img_data['image'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The PyMongo method [insert_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) does not accept arbitrary object. Please see also [PyMongo Tutorial: Inserting a Document](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document)

You should convert your vector object into a document. Please see [MongoDB Data Modelling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) as a starter guide. 
For example, you could design as below:

```
doc = { '0': [-0.078586, 0.0277601, 0.02961, 0.0263595], 
        '1': [-0.078586, 0.0277601, 0.02961, 0.0263595] }
```

Make sure to take into consideration on how you're going to query it later. What's the field that you could use to retrieve the data later. See also [MongoDB Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

An alternative could also be storing the [Python pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) of the object. Example:

```
doc = { 'queryable_value': <pickle> }
```

As you can see there are various ways to design the schema, play around with different designs and see what suits your application best.

Comment: I first converted the vector into a numpy array and then to a python list. It solved the problem. Yes I queried them later on to check for similarity and its working perfectly for my requirements. Thanks for your suggestions/links.